# FFMPEG stream is corrupted on Exoplayer

Tags: ffmpeg, exoplayer, live-streaming, screen-capture

I'm trying to stream my computer's screen with UDP to display in Android with Exoplayer.

I started the stream with this line:

```
ffmpeg -re -f x11grab  -i :0 -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency  -f mpegts udp://192.168.1.107:40001`
```

And received with the media3 Exoplayer:

```
  Surface {
                val exoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Builder(this@MainActivity).build().apply {
                    //Same result as setMediaSource()
                    setMediaItem(MediaItem.fromUri("udp://192.168.1.107:40001"))
                    prepare()
                }

                AndroidView(
                    factory = {
                        PlayerView(it).apply {
                            player = exoPlayer
                        }
                    }
                )
  }
```

But the result is black screen with dots:

[image: Black video with dots]

I can see the stream with `ffplay` it's working perfectly.

I tried to add audio to the stream because I thought a `mpegts` file without audio could cause the problem. I can hear the audio but video still the same.

Then switch to Windows and tried with `gdigrab` and... Yes, still the same.

Thank you for your time in advance.

Comment: Add `-pix_fmt yuv420p`

Comment: That worked! Thanks. If you post it as an answer, I can accept it.